# MS SQL Server and MySQL: Trigger when inserted update (increase)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I Have Drugstore Database

2 tables:

```
Drug :DID , DNumder(is Drug inventory)
Buy_Drug:BID(Autoincrement) , DID ,  Bnumber(is number of Purchase)
```

I want a TRIGGER:
when insert in Buy_Drug Example Bnumber=10  Update Drug by increased Dnumber=Dnumber+10

Example:

```
Buy_Drug:                           Drug:
BID   DID  Bnumber                DID   Dnumber
1     123   44                    111      10
2     111   10                    199       0
```

when insert into Buy_drug  BID=3 DID=123 Bnumber=40
Update Drug:DID=123 Dnumber=44+40=88

IN my trigger*
Dnumber=44+44=88 Mean update by inserted first Record
Too bad my trigger works

My trigger*:

```
create trigger drug_buy
on Buy_Drug
After Insert
as
begin
    Update  Drug
    Set Dnumber=Dnumber+Bnumber
    From Drug JOIN Bying_Drug
    on Drug.DID=Bying_Drug.DID
end
```

Please help me write a working trigger?

Comment: The tag and title contradict - `SqlServer` or `MySql`?

Comment: user3702111:The first priority Sql server---secound Mysql--Tanx A lot

Comment: Don't do this in a trigger. Create a view that sums up units sold and units bought. This will give you the inventory amount. Storing it and recalculating with every insert/update is unnecessary, inefficient and error prone.

Comment: @GarethD That depends on the volume of updates compared with the volume of items to be reported on and the number of reports

Comment: GarethD :what the View code Instead of This Trigger?

Comment: [Here is a quick mockup](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5e2a0/1) of a schema you could use that utilizes a view. For individual requests this should be very fast as it can use only an index seek on both `buy` and `sell` tables. Although as has been pointed out there are some cases where a trigger is the best way to maintain this for reporting, these are (IMO) edge cases. Although even in these edge cases I personally would still rather find an alternative to using a trigger.

Comment: GarethD Thank you very much for your good guidance.Very very Tanx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SqlServer`, you'll need to make use of the `inserted` (and possibly `deleted`) pseudo-tables to do this. Also note of course that DML (Update, Insert etc) to `Buy_Drug` can include a multi row update!:

```
create trigger drug_buy
on Buy_Drug
After Insert
as
begin
    Update  Drug
      Set Dnumber=Dnumber + i.Bnumber
      From Drug JOIN INSERTED i
        on Drug.DID=i.DID
end
```

However, that said, this isn't a good idea to do this work in a trigger, e.g. since it is not concurrent-safe, viz 2 simultaneous inserts could cause the stock to be miscounted. You'll also need mechanisms for downward counts, e.g. for refunds. At the very best, the trigger-updated stock levels would just be indicative ones, where a regular recalc from all data would need to rebase the stock levels more accurately.

Comment: OH -Mr StuartLC-Very Very Very Very Very Very Very .... Tanks For your answered- Very fast and good-Thanks again-

Comment: You are welcome, but, as per the comments, please promise to carefully reconsider whether a trigger is the right tool here.

Comment: Excuse me-What the Mysql code? TANXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: There are lots of examples for MySql triggers, e.g. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f31ea/1. The pseudo tables are called `New` and `Old`, and you also have the `FOR EACH ROW` loop sugar.

Comment: "please promise to carefully reconsider whether a trigger is the right tool here":I think yes the trigger is the right tool here!?-What do you think?

Comment: The pattern here is that when a ledger type table `(Buy_Drug)`  has a transaction, that a cumulative balance table `Drug` needs to update its stock levels. Other ways of doing this include triggering an invalidate event (e.g. on a queue), which when processed, will regenerate the cumulative stock (e.g. every 10 or 15 minutes), or as others have suggested, create a view which `SUM`s the ledger for the current total every time its used (accurate, but slow). Another way to wrap the trigger is ina  stored procedure, which updates both the ledger and the cumulative stock in the same transaction.